# Struggling with Proof Writing. Simple question for demostration.

Tags: proof-writing, automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I am practicing writing proofs over regular expressions. Here is the question:

Show that $(r\cup \varepsilon)^*= r^*$, where $r$ is a string.

Intuitively, the left hand side is the concatenation of zero or more concatenation of $r$ or $\varepsilon$, but for concatenation: $r\varepsilon = r$. Which is essentially the same with the right hand side. Now, I am trying to formalized it.

Proof: Using double inclusion to show equality. First, we do  one direction: show that $(r \cup \varepsilon) \subseteq r^*$, let $w \in (r\cup \varepsilon)^*$, thus, $w$ is the concatenation of either $r$ or $\varepsilon$ for $n$ times, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\geq 0$.

Now, I have a hard time to say that $w$ is the same with $r$, using subsets notations.  I'd appreciate if you can hint me so that I can formalize the word .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using subset notation is not essential.  If you can give a clear proof using mainly words, that is often better than a highly technical algebraic proof.  To prove that ${\rm LHS}\subseteq{\rm RHS}$ I would suggest something like this.

Let $w$ be a word which matches $(r\cup \varepsilon)^*$.  Then by definition $w$ can be written
$$w=w_1w_2\cdots w_n\ ,$$
where $n\ge0$ and every $w_k$ is either $r$ or $\varepsilon$.  Suppose that $m$ of these words $w_k$ are $r$ (and the rest are $\varepsilon$).  Then
$$w=r^m$$
which matches $r^*$.  Therefore $w$ matches the ${\rm RHS}$, and this shows that ${\rm LHS}\subseteq{\rm RHS}$.

**Comment**.  I am more used to working with regular *languages* than regular expressions, though there is no great difference.  You might need to change some of my notation to fit the way you do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I am looking for!